# Where is the Visual Studio test playlist schema?

Tags: visual-studio, nunit, mstest

I'm running tests in Visual Studio 2017 from the Test Explorer window using the NUnit Test Adapter. I use a test playlist file which contains the tests I want to run. The contents of that file look like this:

```
<Playlist Version="1.0">
    <Add Test="MyAssemblyName.MyTestFixture.MyTestMethod()" />
</Playlist>
```

Is there a schema for these Visual Studio playlist files? If so, where is it? If not, can you provide a list here of valid XML attributes for a Playlist file (other than `<Add>`)?

Comment: What is your goal? My goal is to define a playlist as a list of test *projects*, instead of as a list of *individual tests*. As I add unit tests to my project, I want them to be automatically added to my playlist. I have not found a way to do that.

Comment: @WallaceKelly look at my answer, I was able to that what you wanted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to find an XSD too, but I didn't, so I dug on Visual Studio dlls and found this one **Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Core.dll** I used dnSpy to look the C# code, and I found this class `PropertyRule` in `namespace` `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Internal.Playlists`

For the property names all those are valid

```cs
PropertyRule.properties = ImmutableArray.Create<ValueTuple<string, TestPropertyType, string>>(new ValueTuple<string, TestPropertyType, string>[]
{
    new ValueTuple<string, TestPropertyType, string>("Solution", TestPropertyType.Solution, string.Empty),
    new ValueTuple<string, TestPropertyType, string>("Project", TestPropertyType.ProjectName, "TestWindow_ProjectName"),
    new ValueTuple<string, TestPropertyType, string>("Namespace", TestPropertyType.NamespaceName, "TestWindow_NamespaceName"),
    new ValueTuple<string, TestPropertyType, string>("Class", TestPropertyType.ClassName, "TestWindow_ClassName"),
    new ValueTuple<string, TestPropertyType, string>("TargetFramework", TestPropertyType.TargetFramework, "TestWindow_TargetFramework"),
    new ValueTuple<string, TestPropertyType, string>("Outcome", TestPropertyType.Outcome, "TestWindow_Outcome"),
    new ValueTuple<string, TestPropertyType, string>("Trait", TestPropertyType.Trait, "TestWindow_Traits"),
    new ValueTuple<string, TestPropertyType, string>("Test", TestPropertyType.FullyQualifiedName, "TestWindow_FullyQualifiedName"),
    new ValueTuple<string, TestPropertyType, string>("TestWithNormalizedFullyQualifiedName", TestPropertyType.NormalizedFullyQualifiedName, "TestWindow_TestGroup"),
    new ValueTuple<string, TestPropertyType, string>("DisplayName", TestPropertyType.DisplayName, "TestWindow_DisplayName")
});
```

Look the code for the Match attribute

```cs
using System;
    
namespace Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Internal.Playlists
{
  [Flags]
  public enum PropertyRuleMatchFlags
  {
    Contains = 0,
    Not = 1,
    Equals = 2,
    Subset = 4
  }
}
```

Reading the code I was able to edit my playlist XML to ignore some project, so all others are added automatically!